# Why is there a blank space at the top of the questions list?

Tags: support, questions

When I visited Super User this morning, an extra spurious blank space appeared at the top of the list of questions on the home page.

This blank space doesn't appear on any other SE site that I've visited this morning, and did not appear last night.

My environment is: Chrome 22, with Adblock Plus and NotScripts extensions; Windows 8

[image]

Comment: Same thing happens on firefox with ABP. Its definately adblock related.

Comment: It's a *promotion* and gets blocked by ad blockers. Seems to work as designed. You probably blacklist `http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net` or something related, which is where the image and CSS come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a message regarding [Win8 challenge](http://win8challenge.com) over there. Your ad blocker seems to be blocking it

[image]

Comment: Yes, AdBlock for Chrome is enabled. I wonder why this is implemented as an ad?

Comment: @MichaelHampton not too sure how it's implemented - don't see any obvious ad CSS class? (note: I'm a CSS noob - hopefully a dev will leave a comment on this)